# PyTorch C++ FrontEnd returning multiple Tensors in forward

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

I was wonder how can I return a `std::vector<torch::Tensor>` in my forward pass of a Module Class,
I read about the Macro of **FORWARD_HAS_DEFAULT_ARGS** in the docs, but didn’t really
understand how to use it, and also how to use it for making it possible to return a vector in return.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`FORWARD_HAS_DEFAULT_ARGS` is a C++ macro and according to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/define_common_8h_1a4278682b20bb37aa9bbc9317a4aa722b.html):

> This macro enables a module with default arguments in its forward
>   method to be used in a Sequential module.

So it's not what you are after.

I assume you are returning multiple `torch::Tensor` values contained in `std::vector`. You could just do that, but you should appropriately unpack it after returning like this:

```
# Interprets returned IValue as your desired return type
# You may have to use module.forward(inputs) depending how you loaded model
auto outputs = module->forward(inputs).toTensorVector();
# Print first tensor
std::cout << outputs[0] << std::endl;
```

If you want to return multiple values of different types from `forward` method you should just return [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) containing your desired types.

After this you can unpack it like this (for two `torch::Tensor` return values) (source [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15523#issuecomment-456688590)):

```
auto outputs = module->forward(inputs).toTuple();
torch::Tensor out1 = outputs->elements()[0].toTensor();
torch::Tensor out2 = outputs->elements()[1].toTensor();
```

You could also concatenate `pytorch` tensors (if that's all you are returning and they are of the same shape) and use `view` or a-like methods to unpack it. C++ frontend is pretty similar to Python's all in all, refer to docs if in doubt.

Comment: thank you very much, wasn't sure if I could return any type that I wanted but by the way you gave the examples I suppose this IValue can be converted to any type I desire.
Thank you for the support

Comment: @Ellenys check [documentation](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structc10_1_1_i_value.html) to see how you can "interpret"/"cast" IValue (which is a return type from jit compiled models btw.)

Comment: @Ellenys Hi, Will returing std::tuple triggering memory copy which slow down the program ?

Comment: @CoinCheung unlikely, probably copy elision will be done, you shouldn't be concerned with that.